# Using Google Sheet API through the new "Sign in with Google" instead of the old "Google Sign-in"

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0, google-oauth, google-api-js-client

I am threatened by Google to quit using the old (but very effective) "Google Sign-in" because it will be deprecated on 31 Mar 2023. It is fine, but when I go for the new "Sign in with Google", I find that there are no documents explaining how this new authorization flow can integrate with Google Sheet API.

Ironically, even in [Google Sheet API's documentations](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js?hl=zh-tw), the demos there are all still based on the old "Google Sign-in". Can anyone provide demo cases of how to read and insert values into Google Sheet based on the new "Sign in with Google"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Google sheets api quickstart for javascript](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/js)  has been updated to use [web authorization](https://developers.google.com/identity/oauth2/web/guides/overview).

You dont want to use signin unless you are working with Authencation, for google sheets you need authorization.  The new library splits these two concepts.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Sheets API Quickstart</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<p>Sheets API Quickstart</p>

<!--Add buttons to initiate auth sequence and sign out-->
<button id="authorize_button" onclick="handleAuthClick()">Authorize</button>
<button id="signout_button" onclick="handleSignoutClick()">Sign Out</button>

<pre id="content" style="white-space: pre-wrap;"></pre>

<script type="text/javascript">
    /* exported gapiLoaded */
    /* exported gisLoaded */
    /* exported handleAuthClick */
    /* exported handleSignoutClick */

    // TODO(developer): Set to client ID and API key from the Developer Console
    const CLIENT_ID = '<YOUR_CLIENT_ID>';
    const API_KEY = '<YOUR_API_KEY>';

    // Discovery doc URL for APIs used by the quickstart
    const DISCOVERY_DOC = 'https://sheets.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest?version=v4';

    // Authorization scopes required by the API; multiple scopes can be
    // included, separated by spaces.
    const SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets.readonly';

    let tokenClient;
    let gapiInited = false;
    let gisInited = false;

    document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';

    /**
     * Callback after api.js is loaded.
     */
    function gapiLoaded() {
        gapi.load('client', intializeGapiClient);
    }

    /**
     * Callback after the API client is loaded. Loads the
     * discovery doc to initialize the API.
     */
    async function intializeGapiClient() {
        await gapi.client.init({
            apiKey: API_KEY,
            discoveryDocs: [DISCOVERY_DOC],
        });
        gapiInited = true;
        maybeEnableButtons();
    }

    /**
     * Callback after Google Identity Services are loaded.
     */
    function gisLoaded() {
        tokenClient = google.accounts.oauth2.initTokenClient({
            client_id: CLIENT_ID,
            scope: SCOPES,
            callback: '', // defined later
        });
        gisInited = true;
        maybeEnableButtons();
    }

    /**
     * Enables user interaction after all libraries are loaded.
     */
    function maybeEnableButtons() {
        if (gapiInited && gisInited) {
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Sign in the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleAuthClick() {
        tokenClient.callback = async (resp) => {
            if (resp.error !== undefined) {
                throw (resp);
            }
            document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Refresh';
            await listMajors();
        };

        if (gapi.client.getToken() === null) {
            // Prompt the user to select a Google Account and ask for consent to share their data
            // when establishing a new session.
            tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: 'consent'});
        } else {
            // Skip display of account chooser and consent dialog for an existing session.
            tokenClient.requestAccessToken({prompt: ''});
        }
    }

    /**
     *  Sign out the user upon button click.
     */
    function handleSignoutClick() {
        const token = gapi.client.getToken();
        if (token !== null) {
            google.accounts.oauth2.revoke(token.access_token);
            gapi.client.setToken('');
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = '';
            document.getElementById('authorize_button').innerText = 'Authorize';
            document.getElementById('signout_button').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }

    /**
     * Print the names and majors of students in a sample spreadsheet:
     * https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms/edit
     */
    async function listMajors() {
        let response;
        try {
            // Fetch first 10 files
            response = await gapi.client.sheets.spreadsheets.values.get({
                spreadsheetId: '1BxiMVs0XRA5nFMdKvBdBZjgmUUqptlbs74OgvE2upms',
                range: 'Class Data!A2:E',
            });
        } catch (err) {
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = err.message;
            return;
        }
        const range = response.result;
        if (!range || !range.values || range.values.length == 0) {
            document.getElementById('content').innerText = 'No values found.';
            return;
        }
        // Flatten to string to display
        const output = range.values.reduce(
            (str, row) => `${str}${row[0]}, ${row[4]}\n`,
            'Name, Major:\n');
        document.getElementById('content').innerText = output;
    }
</script>
<script async defer src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js" onload="gapiLoaded()"></script>
<script async defer src="https://accounts.google.com/gsi/client" onload="gisLoaded()"></script>
</body>
</html>
```